# JSON schema validate head and tail of and array

Tags: json, jsonschema

Hi I have a simple JSON array
where the first item is always a string
and 2..N items could be boolean or integer. eg.

```
[ "string", 1, 1, true, 1] // valid
[ "string", 1,1,"string" ]  // invalid
[ "string", 1,1,1,1,1,1] // valid
```

I have tried to come up with a json schema to validate this but
unfortunately says all the above are valid. Not sure if its possible to validate this in json shema ie a head and a tail? This list (array) can have any number of items.
my attempt:

```
{
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/head" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/tail" }
    ],
     
     "definitions": {
     "head" :  {
          "type": "string"
         },
    "tail": { "anyOf" : [ 
            { "type" : "number" },
            { "type" : "boolean" }
        ]}
     }
}
```

Comment: What draft (version) of JSON Schema are you using? It may be possible depending on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the array-form of `items` combined with `additionalItems`. `items` describes the head and `additionalProperties` describes the tail.

```json
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [{ "type": "string" }],
  "additionalItems": { "type": ["number", "boolean"] }
}
```

In the new draft 2020-12, the keywords have changed, but you can do the same thing.

```json
{
  "type": "array",
  "prefixItems": [{ "type": "string" }],
  "items": { "type": ["number", "boolean"] }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , would never have guessed that. Could only test first version. Wonder why they change the format and keywords.